# Create a node with it's sub-nodes from more than 1 page anuglar4 and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angular2-services

I am working on a markets application using angular 4 and I have an issue on adding a new category that contains nothing and the name of the category will be the uid of the sub items and each item contains some details of specific item.
On adding new item :- example

- items

  - Category1

    - item1
  - Category2

    - item2

and so on...

I am trying to add new Category and items1 with its details but always fail cause I add each category alone without adding new nodes inside it ... 1st I want to save Category 1 and 2 and so on alone like a UID without adding some nodes inside it. Can I ?

2nd If possible, how to add categories in the items Node as a UID without adding items ?

I used this way,I used this service :-

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase , FirebaseListObservable , FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { itemsCategory } from '../itemsCategory';

@Injectable()
export class AddcategoriesService {

  itemsCategories : FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  itemsCategory : FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

  constructor(public af:AngularFireDatabase) { 
    this.itemsCategories = this.af.list('/restaurants/eldahhan/items') as FirebaseListObservable<itemsCategory[]>;
  }

  addCategory(itemsCategory:itemsCategory){
    return this.itemsCategories.push(itemsCategory);
}

}
```

and this is the category component :-

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
  import { itemsCategory } from '../../itemsCategory';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  import { AddcategoriesService } from '../../services/addcategories.service';


  @Component({
    selector: 'app-categories',
    templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./categories.component.css']
  })
  export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {

    itemsCategory: itemsCategory = {
        cname:""
    };

    constructor(public FlashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService, public Router: Router, public AddcategoriesService: AddcategoriesService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    mySubmit({ value, valid }: { value: itemsCategory, valid: boolean }) {

      if (!valid) {
        this.FlashMessagesService.show('Please right correct info.', { cssclass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
        this.Router.navigate(['app-categories']);
      } else {
        this.AddcategoriesService.addCategory(value);
        this.FlashMessagesService.show('Category Added Successfully.', { cssclass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
        this.Router.navigate(['app-categories']);
      }
    }

  }
```

and finally the html file :-

```
    <style>
    .container {
      padding-top: 100px;
      color: purple;
    }

    .textColor {
      color: purple;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="container col-md-3">
    <h3><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add New Category</h3>
  </div>

  <form novalidate #fo="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="mySubmit(fo)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cname">Category Name : </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cname" [(ngModel)]="itemsCategory.cname" #cname="ngModel" required minlength="3">
    </div> 
    <div *ngIf="cname.errors?.required && cname.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Required **</div>
    <div *ngIf="cname.errors?.minlength && cname.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Please insert more than 3 characters</div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

and that was the interface :-

```
export interface itemsCategory{

    cname?:string;

}
```

Each time it added a new UID in the Path then a cname = Value that I insert

Example :-

- items

  - JOASJOKAOASA4451a5sd1a

    - cname:"any value I insert"

I want it like this :-

- items

  - any value I insert

Comment: Use `set` instead of `push` as shown in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write)

Comment: more details Jen Person ?!

Comment: You can also check out [this documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md) which shows you how to use `set`. `push` creates a new location in the database with a randomly created push ID. That's why you get a push ID instead of the value you added. Instead use `set` or `update` where needed.

Comment: it didn't work @JenPerson !